# Javascript implode each row in table and mixed to another row

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have table like this

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td> no. </td>
   <td> Item </td>
   <td> value </td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td> 1 </td>
   <td> A </td>
   <td> 50 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> 2 </td>
   <td> B </td>
   <td> 25 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> 3 </td>
   <td> C </td>
   <td> 150 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is how to implode my table to array like this

```
[['1';'A';'50'];['2';'B';'25'],['3';'C';'150']]
```

On javascript, i need to send to ajax. If u aks me where myjquery i'm not yet doin, cause i'm still stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$.each` loop

```js
var result = [];
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var tmp = [];
  $(this).children().each(function() {
      tmp.push($.trim($(this).text())); // cut spaces
  })
  result.push(tmp);
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td> no. </td>
   <td> Item </td>
   <td> value </td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td> 1 </td>
   <td> A </td>
   <td> 50 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> 2 </td>
   <td> B </td>
   <td> 25 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> 3 </td>
   <td> C </td>
   <td> 150 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i guess i follow this answer. I will try this.

Comment: @Wolfzmus when your done choose answer and accept it

Comment: This answer uses jQuery and it is not in the tags!

Comment: Tq, it helping my soluiton, i choose this answer ;)

Comment: @YosvelQuintero : u didnt read my question i wanna taht row became array, so i need use jquery and ajax.

Comment: You right guys.. But the jQuery should be added to the tags

Comment: @YosvelQuintero i know, but i didnt add the tags jquery on this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like below,

```
 var result = $("table tbody tr").get().map(function(itm) {
   return $("td", itm).get().map(function(itm){
      return itm.textContent;
   })
 });

 console.log(result);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6ow8jL6g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you don't even need jQuery:

```js
// A utility function so that the code is clearer
function mapSelector(parent, selector, fun){
  return [].map.call(parent.querySelectorAll(selector), fun);
}

// the table, you might want to select a specific one
var tbl = document.querySelector("tbody");

// the operation
var rows = mapSelector(tbl, "tr", tr =>  mapSelector(tr, "td", td => td.textContent));
                       
// just logging
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(rows);
```

```html
<pre id=result></pre>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td> no. </td>
   <td> Item </td>
   <td> value </td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td> 1 </td>
   <td> A </td>
   <td> 50 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> 2 </td>
   <td> B </td>
   <td> 25 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> 3 </td>
   <td> C </td>
   <td> 150 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JavaScript you can do:

```js
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr'),
    resultArr = [].map.call(trs, tr => [].map.call(tr.getElementsByTagName('td'), td => td.innerHTML.trim()));

console.log(resultArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<table><thead><tr><td> no. </td><td> Item </td><td> value </td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td> 1 </td><td> A </td><td> 50 </td></tr><tr><td> 2 </td><td> B </td><td> 25 </td></tr><tr><td> 3 </td><td> C </td><td> 150 </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just loop through all the `<td>` 's within every row and push them into temp array, once the row is complete move that array to main array. perform the same until all `<td>`'s are covered

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(function() {
  var colCount = $('thead td').length;
  var res = [];
  var tempArr = [];
  $('tbody tr td').each(function(index) {
     tempArr.push($(this).text());
     if ((index + 1) % colCount === 0) {
         res.push(tempArr);
         tempArr = [];
     }
  });

  alert(res);
});
```

[Working demo @ jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/775fkLkb/)